# Ruby abort on require need to provide parameter

Tags: ruby, exception, require

I have a Ruby file that has a line as such:

```
abort "ID is less than 1!" if env_id.to_i < 1
```

I am requiring this Ruby file elsewhere and can't pass a parameter when requiring this file. So I keep getting an error where when I try to require the file it aborts with "ID is less than 1!" The env_id is a variable that will be used for uniquely defining a bunch of AWS instances.

Any ideas as to what to do here?

Comment: You have to tell us what `env_id` is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve my problem. I am just going to use **FILE** to see if the file is being run directly or required.